# Toggle Lamp Visibility Blender Game Engine and Python

Tags: python, game-engine

I have this Sun lamp in my scene. I need to toggle the visibility of the lamp with the press of a button. I tried using the Visibility actuator, but it does not remove my lamp because visibility in the Physics panel does not apply to lamp values. I thought of a few ways of toggling the visibility of it, but could not get any of them working:

- Move lamp to another layer on the same scene
- Delete lamp and re-spawn it (I tried `endObject()` but it would never remove the object)
- Change the lamp's brightness value

Remember, this is going to be on a button, so it has to be re-spawnable. If I could get the base code, I can make the toggleable `if` block myself. Also, this is a Python question. Logic blocks take more time to setup than just a simple script. ;)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In python you can access the lamps energy attribute like this:

```
bpy.data.objects["Lamp"].data.energy = 0
```

In the game engine you can toggle the energy by this script (assumes energy value set to 1.0):

```
co = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
lamp = co.owner
toggle = co.sensors["space"] # space is the name of keyboard sensor

if toggle.positive:
    lamp.energy = 1 - lamp.energy
```

[image]